# Unlist components of rasterlayer list into single variables

Tags: r, list, raster

I've read in several .asc files as rasterlayer with tk_choose.files and they are now in a list `xz.list`:

```
library(tcltk)
library(raster)

xz.list <- lapply(tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose Layers"), raster)
```

As the number of components in the list depends on how many .asc files are read in, I'm looking for a way to unlist `xz.list` that every component is written as a variable `x.1` to `x.i`  automatically. I tried this with no luck:

```
for( i in 1:length(xz.list) ){
  assign( paste("x" , i , sep = "." , xz.list[[i]]))
}
```

**UPADATE:**

Sorry for my unclear example. I try to be more precise:

Create a raster list:

```
xz.list <- lapply(1:5,function(x){
r1 <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r1) <- 1:ncell(r1)
r1
})
```

Now I would like to split the list in every single layer like this:

```
x.1 <- xz.list[[1]]
x.2 <- xz.list[[2]]

x.i <- xz.list[[i]]
```

The output should look like this for every layer from `xz.list`:

```
x.1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 120, 60  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 9  (min, max)
```

The problem is, that the number of layers in `xz.list` are varying with the number of layers chosen with `tk_choose.files`. So I need to find a way to split `xz.list` in every of its layers and put every single layer in a variable from `x.1` to `x.i` without knowing the number of layers before. `i` stands for the number of layers in `xz.list`.

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do this? It is covenient to work with rasters in a list like this. If you want a particular raster just use the `\`[[\`` way of subsetting a list to get a single raster, e.g. `xz.list[[1]]` for the first `rasterLayer`.

Comment: I want to transform the raster layers into an vector to use them for a `glm()`.  `[[` just makes a subset of a certain layer, and does not split all layers into variables. Without knowing how many layers I have in `xz.list`, I don't know how to do subsets from all layers.

Comment: @agstudy has done that pretty effectively for you below. `xx <- getValues(stack(xz.list))`, then `glm( response ~ . , data = xx , ...)` where response is the layer with the response variable. and `...` are the other arguments passed to `glm`. This is a rough gist of a suggestio because I do not know your data. I think agstudy has done what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear the expected output since you don't show it in a reproducible example. But Here 3 possibilities.

```
lapply(xz.list,as.matrix)
lapply(xz.list,getValues)
getValues(stack(xz.list))  ## personally I prefer this one
```

For example , I crate the rastes list as:

```
xz.list  <- lapply(1:5,function(x){
   r1 <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
   values(r1) <- 1:ncell(r1)
   r1
})
```

Then , **stack method**

```
getValues(stack(xz.list))
      layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4 layer.5
 [1,]       1       1       1       1       1
 [2,]       2       2       2       2       2
 [3,]       3       3       3       3       3
 [4,]       4       4       4       4       4
 [5,]       5       5       5       5       5
 [6,]       6       6       6       6       6
 [7,]       7       7       7       7       7
 [8,]       8       8       8       8       8
 [9,]       9       9       9       9       9
```

**as.matrix method**

```
 lapply(xz.list,as.matrix)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
......
```

**getValues method**

```
lapply(xz.list,getValues)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
......
```